# Logstash: Nothing displayed on console (Mac)

Tags: logstash, logstash-file

I am trying to set up a very simple logstash config

```
input {
  file {

    path => "/path/to/my/log/file"
    start_position => "beginning"
    ignore_older => 0
  }
}
filter {
}
output {
  stdout {
    codec => rubydebug
  }
}
```

and here is how i start logstash

`[logstash-7.1.1]$ bin/logstash -r -f log.conf`

but here is all i see on the console

```
Sending Logstash logs to path/to/logstash-7.1.1/logs which is now configured via log4j2.properties
[2019-05-28T13:22:57,294][WARN ][logstash.config.source.multilocal] Ignoring the 'pipelines.yml' file because modules or command line options are specified
[2019-05-28T13:22:57,313][INFO ][logstash.runner          ] Starting Logstash {"logstash.version"=>"7.1.1"}
[2019-05-28T13:23:02,904][INFO ][logstash.javapipeline    ] Starting pipeline {:pipeline_id=>"main", "pipeline.workers"=>8, "pipeline.batch.size"=>125, "pipeline.batch.delay"=>50, "pipeline.max_inflight"=>1000, :thread=>"#<Thread:0x7ad3cf30 run>"}
[2019-05-28T13:23:03,254][INFO ][logstash.inputs.file     ] No sincedb_path set, generating one based on the "path" setting {:sincedb_path=>"path/to/logstash-7.1.1/data/plugins/inputs/file/.sincedb_8164b23a475b43f1b0c9aba125f7f5cf", :path=>["/path/to/my/log/file"]}
[2019-05-28T13:23:03,284][INFO ][logstash.javapipeline    ] Pipeline started {"pipeline.id"=>"main"}
[2019-05-28T13:23:03,355][INFO ][filewatch.observingtail  ] START, creating Discoverer, Watch with file and sincedb collections
[2019-05-28T13:23:03,360][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Pipelines running {:count=>1, :running_pipelines=>[:main], :non_running_pipelines=>[]}
[2019-05-28T13:23:03,703][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600}
```

i can see that

```
No sincedb_path set, generating one based on the "path" setting {:sincedb_path=>"path/to/logstash-7.1.1/data/plugins/inputs/file/.sincedb_8164b23a475b43f1b0c9aba125f7f5cf", :path=>["/path/to/my/log/file"]}
```

so the `path` seems correct. Also, my log file is not empty.

What am i doing wrong? Why cant I see the content of my log file on the console?

Answer (score 0):

```
input {
  file {
    path => "/salaries.csv"
    start_position => "beginning"
    type => "data"
  }
}

filter {
  csv{
    separator => ","
  }
}

output {
  stdout { 
    codec => rubydebug 
  }
}
```

This [link](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/struggle-in-export-the-data-from-csv-to-elasticsearch/42211/2?u=croos) may helpful to you